# Error importing LGBMResgressor to lightgib

Tags: python, lightgbm

I'm getting the following error while importing `LGBMResgressor` to `lightgbm`:

```
ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-1a53b4f7b770> in <module>()
      5 from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
      6 import lightgbm as lgb
----> 7 from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor
      8 # from lightgbm.sklearn import LGBMRegressor
      9 from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin, RegressorMixin, clone

ImportError: cannot import name 'LGBMRegressor'
```

`lightgbm`'s version is 2.0.5, and it is installed on Windows 10 by `pip install lightgbm`.

Answer (score 0):

My environment is linux (python 3.6.1) and I installed with `pip install lightgbm`,  opened a ipython terminal and copy your imports and not occurred error, but i can see an 'inconsistence' in your imports. On line six you make:

```
import lightgbm as lgb
```

And on the next line

```
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor
```

On line 6 you already import **all** module as lgb (**line 7 is unnecessary**), for use LGBMRegressor just do:

```
lgb.LGBMRegressor
```

Finnaly, to make sure that the module are insalled, type in a command line:

```
python -c "import lightgbm; print(lightgbm.__version__)"
```

Output:

```
2.0.1
```

Comment: You are right.But on windows,I met this problem,how should I do?

Comment: First of all, make sure that the module is installed with command `python -c "import lightgbm; print(lightgbm.__version__)"` in line command, the output will be the package's version (2.0.1 in my context). If ok, try to remove line 7 of your imports and when you need to use lightgbm, use this way: lgb.lightgbm

Comment: Another test you can do is simply remove the line 6. Keep in mind that you need to be sure that the package is installed, don't forget of the command: `python -c "import lightgbm; print(lightgbm.__version__)"`